# Can I have my Free shield again if I attacked?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Would I lose my Free Town Shield if I attacked with the shield? If yes would I have it again?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to launch an attack while you have a shield, it will give you a warning saying that you will lose your shield if you attack. As soon as you click 'OK', you lose the shield, even if you do not launch an attack.

You can get a shield back by either buying it, or when someone attacks you and does atleast 40% damage to your town, or gets any stars. You will not get it back otherwise.

Comment: You can also gain a shield if an attacker destroys a single building in your village: your town hall. In fact, if you want to encourage people to grant you a shield without stealing all of the resources in your base, it would be best for you to put your town hall outside of your base so that it can be easily destroyed.

Comment: Good point, I forgot that getting any stars against you would trigger a shield

Answer (score 0):

If you attack while you have an active shield,the shield will be gone if you have searched for a base. To recover your shield: 1.Use gems to buy a shield. 2.Someone has to at least 40% your base to have a shield. Or 3.Save your shield.